# Open Source C# Syntax Editor with Intellisense

Tags: c#, .net, editor, intellisense, syntax-highlighting

Can anyone please suggest me a good open source C# code editor **control** with syntax highlighting and intellisense to use in my application. I am not asking for any IDE like VS or #develop, I need only a winform code editor control so that I can use it in my application for scripting.
Can you please suggest me a good one ...

I found ScintillaNET, but I want some other alternative..

Comment: Why can't you use ScintillaNET?

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of it, though it's not Open Source, but Actipro Software SyntaxEditor is quote good: http://www.actiprosoftware.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering all the options I decided to go for ScintillaNet, cause it is very easy to use.

Comment: A bit unfair to mark your decision as the correct answer. The person who suggested ScintillaNet should have got credit for it.

Comment: It was good to post what you did finally...

Answer (score 12):

Sounds like you want something like Avalon Edit:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx

The editor for SharpDevelop, but its also a component you can download and use on your own stuff.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to host #Develop in your application,

http://laputa.sharpdevelop.net/AnnouncingSharpDevelopForApplicationsSDA.aspx

Comment: Is it free? I mean can I use it in my open source application?

Comment: It is open source under LGPL.

Comment: thanks but I dont know LGPL requirements and I dont have time to read it all. if you know please tell me if I can use it in my open source application

Comment: If you are going to work in the open source world, you have to learn most of the open source licenses whether you like it or not (have time or not). So please spare some time on them, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License. The simple answer to your query in this case is YES, you can use it in an open source project, but you still need to pay attention to the terms.

Answer (score 3):

Wpf Source Code Editor is an alternative for ScintillaNET

Answer (score 2):

I used the SharpDevelop code to do this a while back. Another alternative might be to take a look at the code for MonoDevelop and see if you can pull out the part you need and reuse that. Technically MonoDevelop is a fork of SharpDevelop but its been a long time so they might be completely different now.